# what should i do when the number of data of diffrent topics obtained from LDA varied a lot

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-mining, lda

Hi I am using LDA to do the clustering and detect the topics in the text data. However, I find that for one specific topic the amount of the data is extremely high when compared to other detected topics, just like the picture below:
[image: clustering result]

I am a newbie of using LDA so I am wondering could anyone could give me some hints on how to modify the model or the parameters?

Comment: Maybe they *are* all about the same topic?

Comment: If you want advice on how to modify parameter, it'd help a lot if you provided the parameters and implementation you're using...